# How to appropriately change the filename for ng2-file-uploader in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload

I want to change the name of my image in angular via the ng2-file-uploader and then pass it to my multer in my node.js.

Everything is working fine. I am able to receive the image and it is being stored in my upload directory on server side. It is just that I don't know where to change the image name. I tried it in the onCompleteItem method but nothing. Here is some code:

```
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'name',
  templateUrl: './some.html',
  styleUrls: [./some.css]
})
export class ComponentName {
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: "myurl", itemAlias: 'myPhoto' });

  ngOnInit(){
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {};
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
      //create my name
      item.file.name = "my name"
      alert('File uploaded');
    }; 
    this.uploader.uploadAll();
  }
}
```

I just want to change the name so that I can store it in my database together with the other input values that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple.
You almost got it, but you chose the wrong method.
You can change the file name in the `onAfterAddingFile` method.
Below I can show you some code

```
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'name',
  templateUrl: './some.html',
  styleUrls: [./some.css]
})
export class ComponentName {
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: "myurl", itemAlias: 'myPhoto' });

  //new name string variable
  newFileName : string;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
      //create my name
      file.file.name = "new name";
      //save in variable
      newFileName = file.file.name;
    };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
      alert('File uploaded');
    }; 
    this.uploader.uploadAll();
  }
}
```

That way you can pass a complete new file name or you could use javascript's string replace method and regex to replace characters in your file name.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onAfterAddingAll` as workaround:

```
 this.uploader.onAfterAddingAll = (files: FileItem[]) => {
        files.forEach(fileItem => {
            fileItem.file.name = fileItem.file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
            (<any>fileItem).previewUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file)));
        });
    };
```